# Creating a pdf report from qtablewidgets and plots in a pyqt5 GUI

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt5, reporting, qtablewidget

[image]

I have a PyQt5 GUI where I retrieve data from a DB and insert into multiple table widgets and make plot widgets. I would like to make a PDF report out of these widgets' (tables and plots) contents. What is the most efficient way to do this in PyQt5?

I am using the following function but the quality of the output is not good. Also how can I set the custom size of widget in pdf?

Below is the MRE.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.table = QTableWidget(rows, columns, self)

        self.table.setSpan(0, 0, 1, 5)
        self.table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Master Title"))

        self.table.setSpan(1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.table.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Title 1"))
        self.table.item(1, 0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.table.setSpan(2, 0, 2, 2)
        self.table.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Merge 2x2"))
        self.table.item(2, 0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        for column in range(columns - 1):
            for row in range(4, rows - 1):
                item = QTableWidgetItem('Text%d' % row)
                self.table.setItem(row, column, item)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.handleSave(self.table, 'table1')

    def handleSave(self, widget, filename):
        printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.HighResolution)
        printer.setPageSize(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.A6)
        printer.setColorMode(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.Color)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName(filename + '.pdf')
        pixmap = QtWidgets.QWidget.grab(widget).scaled(
            printer.pageRect(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.DevicePixel).size().toSize(),
            QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(printer)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap)
        painter.end()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(10, 5)
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is the meaning of *but the quality of the output is not good*?

Comment: @eyllanesc added image

Comment: great, please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc  added MRE.

Comment: When I open the pdf it is zoomed 300%+. I reduce to 100% and this is what I get.

Comment: anyone can help? or any other suggestions?